Mass change all of the tables that have a BIT data type to a default of 0 False
I have a few databases to change over as I need to convert all of the old VB.NET code to Entity Framework and C#.
I was wonder if this was the best way to get this accomplished. I wrote the following and I tested it and seems to do what I need but I do have to drop all of the statistics on each table for this to work.
First Step
/*

Drop all Statistics

*/
DECLARE @TableName SYSNAME; 
DECLARE @StatName SYSNAME;

DECLARE StatCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT 
    t.name,
    s.name 
FROM 
    sys.tables t
JOIN 
    sys.stats s ON t.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE 
    s.name LIKE '_dta_stat%';

OPEN StatCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM StatCursor INTO @TableName, @StatName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Drop the statistic
    EXEC ('DROP STATISTICS '+ @TableName +'.'+ @StatName+';')

    FETCH NEXT FROM StatCursor INTO @TableName, @StatName;
END;

CLOSE StatCursor;
DEALLOCATE StatCursor;

Second step is to run the updates
/*

To Change all of the bit columns to be not NULL and have a default of 0

*/

declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @dbName nvarchar(50)
declare @schema nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @colname VARCHAR(128)

DECLARE [bit] CURSOR FOR

SELECT QUOTENAME(db.name)
        ,QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(c.[object_id]))
        , QUOTENAME(t.name)
        , QUOTENAME(c.name)
FROM 
    sys.columns c
JOIN 
    sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
JOIN 
    sys.databases db ON t.object_id = OBJECT_ID(db.name + '.' + s.name + '.' + t.name)
WHERE db.database_id > 5
    AND c.system_type_id = 104 AND c.is_nullable = 1
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0

OPEN [bit]

FETCH NEXT FROM [bit] INTO @dbName, @schema, @tableName, @colname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
        PRINT 'UPDATE ' + @dbName + '.' + @schema + '.' + @tableName + ' SET ' + @colname + '=0 WHERE ' + @colname + ' IS NULL;'
        PRINT 'GO'
        PRINT 'ALTER TABLE ' + @dbName + '.' + @schema + '.' + @tableName + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + replace(replace(@colname,'[',''),']','') + '_FalseByDefault DEFAULT (0) FOR ' + @colname + ';'
        PRINT 'GO'
        PRINT 'ALTER TABLE ' + @dbName + '.' + @schema + '.' + @tableName + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + @colname + ' BIT NOT NULL;'
        PRINT 'GO'

        FETCH NEXT FROM [bit] INTO @dbName, @schema, @tableName, @colname
END

CLOSE           [bit]
DEALLOCATE      [bit]

GO


You should probably remove the C# and Visual Studio tags. This is purely a SQL question

Thanks yep agree did not even think of that just put them in on muscle memory!

What happens if you try and change the column type without dropping the statistics? Does altering the column and adding the constraint add new statistics?

For reliability you might want to wrap replace(replace(@colname,'[',''),']','') + '_FalseByDefault and all usages of @dbName, @schema, @tableName, @colname and @StatName in QUOTENAME() instead (remove the replace logic).

@DaleK, if you do not drop that stats is give a alter error on the add constraints and fails

Ar they must be manually created statistics. Assuming they were created for a reason you probably want to re-create them afterwards.

That said, there is not really a question here - is this the bear way to do X is off topic for this site.
